# Solving OCaml Problems

Tags: ocaml

> Define a function `sign` which given an integer returns 1 if it is positive, -1 if it is negative and 0 if it is zero.

my solutions

solution 1

```
let sign i = if i!=0 then (if i<0 then -1 else 1) else 0;;
```

solution 2

```
let sign x =
  if x = 0 then 0 else
    if x<0 then -1 else 1;;
```

It doesn't work for negative numbers but it works for positive numbers and zero.

I receive the following error

```
Error: This expression has type int -> int
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

Comment: Looks like your solutions are right, I guess the way you are calling them could be "wrong". In OCaml, if you call `# sign -1`, the `-` is also an OCaml valid function and will raise this type error. You can  wrap the number in parenthesis or use the `~` operator. In other words: `# sign (-1)` or `# sign ~-1`. Hope it help you.

Comment: I completely agree with @JoVi, just want to say things a little differently in case it helps. Both of your functions look correct. It's very likely your testing is wrong, again just as @JoVi says. The expression `sign -1` in OCaml is parsed as subtracting 1 from `sign`.  You need to parenthesize as `sign (-1)` to get it parsed as a call to your function. Both functions return the correct answer when called this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments, your functions look correct.

You are most likely calling it as: `sign -1` which is parsed as `(sign) - (1)`. Thus the compiler complaint that a function was encountered where an expression of type `int` was expected.

This can be overcome in two ways. Using parens to disambiguate, or using the `~-` prefix.

```
sign (-1)
```

```
sign ~-1
```

As an additional note, this can also be implemented in terms of a comparison to `0`.

```
let sign n = compare n 0
```

Or if you're of a slightly more Haskell-y mindset.

```
let sign = Fun.flip compare 0
```

As a further aside, I would suggest the following style:

```
let sign x =
  if x = 0 then 0 
  else if x<0 then -1 
  else 1
```

As opposed to:

> ```
> let sign x =
>   if x = 0 then 0 else
>     if x<0 then -1 else 1
> ```